# Set next.js pageExtensions to not build *.dev.* pages

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm working on a Next.js (***v12.3***) app and I'm facing an issue regarding the exclusion of page files with a `*.dev.*` extension from the build process. In my `next.config.js`, I have set up the `pageExtensions` to customize the behavior based on the env.

My goal is to exclude pages with the `*.dev.*` from the build when in a production env, but include them when in a dev env.

But actually, every pages return 404 :c

I'm seeking guidance and advice on properly configuring the next.config.js file to achieve the desired behavior. How can I ensure that the page files with the `*.dev.*` extension are excluded from the build process only in the production environment, while still being included during development?

Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your time and assistance!

```js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['ui']);
const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require('next/constants');

module.exports = withTM((phase) => {
  const generatePageExtensions = (prodExtensions) => {
    const isDev = phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER;

    console.log('isDev', isDev);
    console.log('phase', phase);
    console.log('PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER', PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER);

    if (isDev) {
      const devExtensions = prodExtensions.map((extension) => {
        const devExtension = `dev.${extension}`;

        return devExtension;
      });

      return [...prodExtensions, ...devExtensions];
    }

    return prodExtensions;
  };

  return {
    i18n: {
      locales: ['en-US'],
      defaultLocale: 'en-US',
    },
    pageExtensions: generatePageExtensions(['page.tsx', 'page.ts']),
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
      domains: ['cdn.sanity.io'],
    },
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone with the same problem i solved with:

```js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['ui']);
const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require('next/constants');

module.exports = (phase) => {
  const generatePageExtensions = (prodExtensions) => {
    const isDev = phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER;

    if (isDev) {
      const devExtensions = prodExtensions.map((extension) => {
        const devExtension = `dev.${extension}`;

        return devExtension;
      });

      return [...prodExtensions, ...devExtensions];
    }

    return prodExtensions;
  };

  return withTM({
    i18n: {
      locales: ['en-US'],
      defaultLocale: 'en-US',
    },
    pageExtensions: generatePageExtensions(['page.tsx', 'page.ts']),
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
      domains: [''],
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).